# ListFragment doesn't show firebase/firebaseui items

Tags: android, firebase, android-volley, android-listfragment, firebaseui

As the title says, my `ListFragment` doesn't show items retrieved from firebase, here my code:

CONTAINER:

```
    public class MainPageLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
private BottomBar mBottomBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page_login);

    // mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar = BottomBar.attachShy((CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.myCoordinator),
            findViewById(R.id.myScrollingContent), savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setFragmentItems(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.fragmentContainer,
            new BottomBarFragment(ChatListFragment.newInstance(R.layout.chat_list_fragment,0), R.drawable.ic_action_user, "Chat"),
            new BottomBarFragment(PollListFragment.newInstance(R.layout.poll_list_fragment,1), R.drawable.ic_assessment, "Sondaggi"),
            new BottomBarFragment(ContactListFragment.newInstance(R.layout.contact_list_fragment,2), R.drawable.ic_contacts, "Contatti")
    );

    mBottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#C83F09");
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
    // lose the current tab on orientation change.
    mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}}
```

CONTAINER XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myCoordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

LISTFRAGMENT JAVA

```
public class ChatListFragment extends ListFragment {
ListView usr_chats;
Button btn_crea;
StringBuilder total;
TextView nochat;
RequestQueue queue;
TextView chat_item;
FirebaseListAdapter<String> Fireadapter;
View v;

public ChatListFragment(){}

public static ChatListFragment newInstance(int res, int i){
    ChatListFragment f = new ChatListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("res", res);
    args.putInt("choice",i);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_fragment, container, false);
    nochat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.no_chat);
    btn_crea = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crea_chat);
    usr_chats =  (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    //-------------------------------
    return v;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    total = new StringBuilder();
    total.append("");

    btn_crea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),contacts.class);
            intent.putExtra("KEY",total.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getContext());
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = getActivity().openFileInput("usr_basekey");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        r.close();
        inputStream.close();
        //Log.d("VOTA",total.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("VOTA", "FILE NON TROVATO:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("VOTA", "IO EXCEPTION:" + e.getMessage());
    }
    Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://fiery-fire-7347.firebaseio.com/user/"+total.toString());

    myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            String user_params = snapshot.getValue().toString();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonO = new JSONObject(user_params);
                String user_name = jsonO.getString("name");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
        }

    });
    Firebase chats = myFirebaseRef.child("chatadded");
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    Log.d("VOTA","preListAdapter");
    Fireadapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            String.class,
            R.layout.chat_user_list,
            chats
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, final String s, int i) {
            chat_item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_name_for_users);

            String url = "https://fiery-fire-7347.firebaseio.com/chats/"+s+"/nomeChat.json";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("VOTA","ResponseAdapter-"+response);
                    chat_item.setText(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("VOTA", "Volley Error: " + error);
                }
            });
            queue.add(stringRequest);

        }
    };
    usr_chats.setAdapter(Fireadapter);

    Log.d("VOTA", "postListAdapter");
    usr_chats.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivityHome.class);
            intent.putExtra("nChat","");
            intent.putExtra("myKey",total.toString());
            intent.putExtra("kChat", Fireadapter.getItem(position));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

//-----------------------------

}}
```

LISTVIEW XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.gitlab.votateam.votateam.MainPage">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/crea_chat"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<TextView
    android:textColor="#737373"
    android:id="@+id/no_chat"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="102dp" />
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Crea Chat"
    android:id="@+id/crea_chat"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ITEMS XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/def_groupchat_profile"
     />
<TextView
    android:textColor="#737373"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/chat_name_for_users"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm sure the code works, and the error should be related to XML because my log shows the correct "response" from the firebase DB.

Comment: Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);  try this

Answer (score 0):

You're firing an async request to get a string `StringRequest`. By the time that string comes back, Android is not expecting changes to the view anymore and it doesn't update the view.

The solution is typically to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d("VOTA","ResponseAdapter-"+response);
        chat_item.setText(response);
    }
}, ...
```

Comment: I tried to add `notifyDataSetChanged()` just under the  `usr_chats.setAdapter(Fireadapter)` but nothing changed. The problem is that, when I extend `Activity` instead `ListFragment` the  code works without problems (also without `notifyDataSetChanged()` ) because I think `FirebaseListAdapter` has an internal call for the update, but when I exend `ListFragment` then nothing is showed

Comment: `FirebaseListAdapter` is unaware of whether you use it in a fragment or in an activity. It just calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` when... uhm... the data set has changed.

Comment: That exactly what I thought, and this for this reason I can't understand why my code doesn't works. I any case I try also to change from  `Fireadapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(...)` to `chats.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {...}`, modifying where was necessary, but as above code nothing changed